# Limit as $x$ tend to zero of: $x/[\ln (x^2+2x+4) - \ln(x+4)]$

Tags: limits, logarithms, rational-functions

Without making use of LHôpital's Rule solve:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {x\over \ln (x^2+2x+4) - \ln(x+4)}$$

$ x^2+2x+4=0$ has no real roots which seems to be the gist of the issue.

I have attempted several variable changes but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach **without L'Hopital's rule**.
$$\lim_{x\to 0} {x\over \ln (x^2+2x+4) - \ln(x+4)}=\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over {1\over x}\ln {x^2+2x+4\over x+4}}=\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over \ln \big ({x^2+2x+4\over x+4}\big)^{1\over x}}$$
but 
$$({x^2+2x+4\over x+4}\big)^{1\over x}=({x^2+x+x+4\over x+4}\big)^{1\over x}=\big(1+{x^2+x\over x+4}\big)^{1\over  x}=\big(1+{ x(x+1)\over x+4}\big)^{1\over  x}=\big(1+\color\red x({x+1\over x+4})\big)^{1\over \color\red x}$$ which tends to $e^{1\over 4}$ as $x$ goes to $0$. So the original limit is ${1\over \ln{e^{1\over 4}}}=\color\red  4$

Comment: I understand the process which you describe in it's broader form but I fail to grasp the transformation of the rational expression you describe in the second paragraph can you write it down?

Comment: I edited the answer and added some details. Is it clear now? @PauloMartins

Comment: Because lim as n-> 0 of(1+1/n)^n = e correct? @Fermat

Comment: Yes but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+{1\over n})^n=e$$ and in general $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+{k\over n})^n=e^k$$

Answer (score 3):

By [L'Hospital](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{2x + 2}{x^2 + 2x + 4} - \frac{1}{x+4}} = \color{red} 4$$

Answer (score 3):

Outline: Flip it over, and calculate
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x^2+2x+4)-\ln(4)}{x} -\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+4)-\ln(4)}{x}.$$
We recognize the two limits as derivatives at $0$ of $\ln(x^2+2x+4)$ and $\ln(x+4)$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, thank you. For the sake of familiarity I had used $h$, then decided not to, but did not manage to change all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - in any case, nice answer!

Comment: You are welcome. I consider the Taylor series approach the natural one, because it directly addresses the behaviour of the functions near $0$. But because of the order in which such things are done in standard North American calculus courses, Taylor series might be dealt with *after* this kind of limit problem.

Comment: What is the property that makes this particular and other limits in general "fliparoveble"

Comment: They basically all are. We have $\lim{x\to a}f(x)=L\ne 0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{L}$. And we can even say useful things when $L= 0$, but $L\ne 0$ in this problem.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

In the eternal words of Claude Leibovici, love Taylor Series.

We have

\begin{align*}
\ln(x^{2}+2x+4) &= \ln(4) + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^{2}}{8} + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})\\
\ln(x+4) &=\ln(4)  + \frac{x}{4} -\frac{x^{2}}{32} + \mathcal{O}(x^{3}).
\end{align*}

So

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {x\over \ln (x^2+2x+4) - \ln(x+4)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\ln(4) + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^{2}}{8} - \left( \ln(4)  + \frac{x}{4} -\frac{x^{2}}{32}\right) + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\frac{x}{4} + \frac{5x^{2}}{32} + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})}.$$

Divide the numerator and denominator by the lowest power of $x$ in the denominator to get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\frac{x}{4} + \frac{5x^{2}}{32} + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x} x}{\frac{1}{x}\left( \frac{x}{4} + \frac{5x^{2}}{32} + \mathcal{O}(x^{3})\right)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{5x}{32} + \mathcal{O}(x^{2})} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}} = 4.$$

Comment: In the final step of the Taylor series are you stating the inverse of the property lim x-> 00 of (a0x^n + a1x^n-1 ... an) = lim x->00 a0x^n? @JessicaK

Comment: @PauloMartins I am having some trouble understanding the equation that you wrote. I simply dropped the higher order terms of the polynomials because they do not affect the limit, but I edited my answer to avoid doing this.

Comment: @PauloMartins If "00" is supposed to be $\infty$, hopefully by looking at the above modification, you should be able to convince yourself of an analogous property for limits of polynomials towards $0$ instead of $\infty$.

Comment: Yes it was supposed to mean exactly that. And I have convinced myself of such property. Thanks

Comment: Thanks you, JessicaK for having noticed my love for Taylor ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{\ln \left( \frac{x^2+2x+4}{x+4}\right)}$$

Apply L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\frac{x^2+8x+4}{(x+4)(x^2+2x+4)}}$$

Then simply evaluate the limit:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{0^2+8\times0+4}{(0+4)(0^2+2\times0+4)}} = \frac{1}{\frac{4}{16}} = 4$$

Comment: Why not apply L'Hopital's rule with the difference of two logarithms rather than making it into a logarithm of a quotient first.  That way you don't need the quotient rule. ${}\qquad{}$